# Clean unwanted code repetition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way not to duplicate the same in JavaScript only to write it once and use it twice? 
When I tried to use the class it didn't work.

HTML:

```
<img id="Image" src="1.jpg" alt="1" style="width:50%;max-width:30%">
<img id="Imagee" src="2.jpg" alt="1" width="300" height="200" />
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
            <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var img = document.getElementById("Image");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
/*duplicate */
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var img = document.getElementById("Imagee");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Why are you repeating it? Are you writing your javascript directly in the html code?

Comment: Always surround JS in <script></script> tags

Comment: I do not mix html with js, this is just an example of html and js

Comment: Maybe you're looking for how to define a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code block. Call the same code block through a function by passing the dynamic image `ID`.

```
<img id="Image" src="1.jpg" alt="1" style="width:50%;max-width:30%">
<img id="Imagee" src="2.png" alt="1" width="300" height="200" />
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
        <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

modalContent("Image");
modalContent("Imagee");

function modalContent(imageId) {

    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    var img = document.getElementById(imageId);
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

}   
</script>
```